# Ember data not populating model

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm attempting to grab some data from my Rails API and display it in the template.
I'm very new to ember so the simpler the explanation the better and forgive me if this is a very stupid question.

The problem seems to be that the api data is not reaching the model correctly, it works when I have static fixture data but not for server data. The Get request to the server is going through and I'm getting a good response, so there must be something wrong with how the json is moved to the model.

My route in `routes/external/jobs.js`

```
import Ember from 'ember';

 export default Ember.Route.extend({ 
   model() {
   return this.store.findAll('job');
}
```

});

My job model in `models/job.js`

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    id: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I am expecting my API to return data in the form

```
{
  "jobs": [
      {
        id: "jfdsa132113",
        title: "developer",
        type: "Job",
        body: "lorem ipsum",
        published_at: date,
        tags: [
              "some stuff",
              "more stuff"
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "fdsafd3432",
        title: "designer",
        type: "Job",
        body: "lorem ipsum",
        published_at: date,
        tags: [
              "some stuff",
              "more stuff"
        ]
      }
   ]
}
```

My router

```
Router.map(function () {

 //index route

this.route('external', function () {
   this.route('jobs');
   this.route('support');

});

export default Router;
```

Comment: Hey sidenote, the current syntax is `{{#each model as |job|}}`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I updated it, wasn't the issue though

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding with regards to `DS.Model`s, you should take a look at the guides, specifically http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/models/finding-records/.

Assuming the route and template are properly set up, and that `ApplicationAdapter` is extending `RESTAdapter`/`ActiveModel Adapter` — see expected JSON formats [here](http://andycrum.github.io/ember-data-model-maker/) —, I believe the problem is in `models/jobs.js`, which is unnecessary.

Ember Data should make the right request to `/jobs` when you do `store.findAll('job')`. Try removing `models/jobs.js` and `adapters/jobs.js`, and doing the following:

```
// routes/external/jobs.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('job');
  }
});
```

If this doesn't help try also posting your router and any errors you get.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe the applicationadapter is set up properly. You were right the adapter wasn't necessary, but deleting the model gives the "Error while processing route: external.jobs  Expected to find: 'model:job' within 'project/models/job' but got 'undefined" error

Comment: Strange, don't you still have that model?

Comment: Alright I got rid of the jobs model and now just have one job.js

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear, but I've updated the question to reflect my app currently so everything above is what I currently have. I'm getting no errors, but the data still isn't being sent to the template. The get request is going through though since I can see the json result in the network dev tools

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your models are loading up fine from your API I think the issue is in your template.

According to the docs, you need to access the attributes of each model explicitly. http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/templates/displaying-a-list-of-items/

So rather than `{{title}}` use `{{job.title}}`.

```
{{#each model as |job|}}
   <a href={{job.title}}>
      <div class="info">
          <div class="title">{{job.body}}</div>
      </div>
   </a>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This didn't solve it though. I think it is an issue with the model data reaching the template, maybe a naming error or something is in the wrong spot?

Comment: Sorry I can't be much more help. I'd use Ember Inspector to make sure your data is loaded up into the App and I'd also throw a `{{debugger}}` statement into the loop in the template and checking the `model` and `job` variables. Perhaps rig up a jsbin for this post as well because it is hard to know exactly what is going on.

http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/ember-inspector/installation/

http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/templates/development-helpers/

Comment: That's alright, any help is better than none. According to the ember inspector my model for the route is <DS.RecordArray:ember767>, and when I check the data tab and look in the job model that is the same model, but the content is [ ] and the length is 0. I'm not sure what that means. I can see the get request returning the proper json in the network tab, so maybe it just isnt being set to the store?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it

adding the file 
    `serializers/job.js`
with the lines

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

   export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {

});
```

I did not build the api and I noticed that some of the id's were underscored convention. More can be read about it here http://ember-doc.com/classes/DS.ActiveModelSerializer.html